# How to get albums photos using Facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm trying to get Facebook albums photos using graph API, but the issue is that i can only fetch the albums photos for the account(deepak@triusmail.com) by which I have created App.

If I try to login from this account then I can fetch the details but if I go for other Facebook account then It will not work.

Can anybody have time to look into [this](http://triusapp.com/fb/index.html)

Please review the response in console after login.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that If our app was created after April 30th 2014, then we have to get our app reviewed by Facebook to gather albums photos.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_login
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Thanks